# Disabling interpolation, when zooming in on an <img>

Tags: css, html, image

When you have an img element on a HTML5 page, interpolation is applied to the img,
when the user zooms in on the page.
But if you for example have some pixelart on your page and don't want the interpolation,
simply because it's ruining the sharp pixels, what do you do?
My question is simple: How do you disable interpolation in pure HTML5/CSS?

Answer (score 2):

```
img {
    image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
    image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
    image-rendering: crisp-edges;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;
}
```

This will affect rendering when you set img dimensions (in CSS or attribute) but is not guaranteed to affect rendering when user zooms page.

[MDN: image-rendering CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering)

Comment: `crisp-edges` wasn't, what I needed, because it still does interpolation, when zoomed/scaled. However the MDN page, you linked, was useful. I found, that I needed the `pixelated` option, because it completely disables interpolation. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

in Chrome use:

```
img {
    image-rendering: pixelated;
}
```

more about this property - https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/i/image-rendering/